# Maxima personality failure 38 on Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu

Tags: maxima, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu on my windows installed through `Windows Subsystem for Linux`. I installed Maxima using `apt`. But when trying to run Maxima I get the error:

> personality failure 38

What is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: A web search for "Windows Ubuntu personality failure 38" seems to turn up some hits which you can review. But Maxima runs on Windows and there is an installer for it. Maybe you can just install Maxima on Windows and use that.

Comment: @robert-dodier indeed I have searched and if there was a proper answer I wouldn't ask here. I also have maxima installed on my windows, but because I'm using the the emulated ubuntu as my development platform I would like to have everything there.

Comment: Foad, unfortunately I don't know anything more about that error. At this point my very general advice is to try to work in one system or the other (Windows or Linux). Perhaps you can install your computer as a dual-boot system. My experience with trying to wedge Linux into Windows is that it never quite works right, there's always some problems. I have been happier (i.e. fewer unexpected problems) either using Windows entirely or Linux entirely. Of course, your experience may be different. I wish you the best, good luck.